# How to handle wait for input signal in python?

Tags: java, python

I have a python code that has some inputs:

```
a = input("first input:")
b = input("second input:")
```

I run it from java:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("python3", scriptPath).start();
```

but running from python is also suitable for me.

Is it possible to catch signal from python process when it waits for input and handle it somehow? For instance, on the first input I want to write some text to `process.getOutputStream()` and on the second input I want to kill process.

I found that there is SIGTTIN signal for terminal input. And I tried to do it in python:

```
def interrupted(signum, frame):
    exit()

signal.signal(signal.SIGTTIN, interrupted)
a = input()
```

but it did not work out.

Comment: What does "did not work out" mean? Please be more specific. Which OS are you using? There are some subtle differences in how OSes handle signals. BTW, don't use `exit` in a script, it's only for use in the interactive interpreter, and it may behave oddly, or not even exist, in a script. Instead, use `sys.exit`, or `raise SystemExit`.

Comment: I'm using macOS High Sierra, python 3.7. I tried `sys.exit` but it didn't work too. Input is not interrupted and function `interrupted` is not called.

Comment: What is it that you want exactly? I've tried your code and sent the listening process `SIGTTIN`, the handler kicks in as expected  (if you ran your script in the background, it would also exit as `SIGTTIN` is part of terminal job control to let process know its stdin is not available). So are you looking for specific signal? Or wait for input before reading? Or just perform some action once read completes (which you would not need to involve signals at all).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution for the question that I asked. But I solve the initial problem by replacing `input`  function on my own.

```
__builtins__.input = myfunc
```